# Define an homemade pow function as an exercise

Tags: c++, pow, sqrt

On my IT lessons i got this task:

> Write function where user puts integer m (m>1) and non-negative n and
>   the function returns `std::pow(n, 1.0/m)`. You cant use any library.

Which means, i have to use pow function... but i can't use it.
Since its not 2^2 or 2^7, i cant use simple for loop.
I've tried doing anything like adding, multiplication, nothing worked anywhere near.

Any ideas?

FYI:
It's not my homework, teacher just gave me this task to learn something.

Comment: Can you do this on paper, step by step, without a calculator?  If so, then you CAN do it with a for loop using addition, multiplication etc.

Comment: You have to calculate `a^b`. You already have `*`, `exp()` and `log()`. Try to invent a formula given these.

Comment: How did mathematicians calculate the `mth` root of a number before there was C++ and `pow`?

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 replacing a library function (```pow()```) with two library functions (```log()``` and ```exp()```) do not really eliminate the dependency from a library

Answer (score 2):

`std::pow(n, 1.0/m)` is the `m`-th root of `n`. You can find an helpful [algorithm of how to implement it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm) on wikipedia:

1. Make an initial guess `x0`
2. Set `x = 1.0/m * [ (n-1)*x + n/pow(x,m-1) ]`<sup>1</sup>
3. Repeat step 2 until `x` is only changed a little or maxiter has been reached.

<sup>1)</sup> Obviously, you'll need to define `pow(x,y)` for integer `y`, which is trivial.

Comment: It does not affect the triviality, but only ```y``` will be an integer for that 'internal' ```pow(x,y)``` function